# Can I disable SPDY on a HTTPS AppEngine request?

Tags: google-app-engine, https, spdy

If I use HTTPS on App Engine, Google servers automatically serve it using SPDY to compatible browsers. Is there a way to override this (any settings or special header)? I want to use old HTTP/1.1 when using HTTPS